# Pass multiple arguments through Eval to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I am trying very hard to pass three parameters to a javascript function from within a itemtemplate of a gridview:

For one parameter, it works fine:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypComment" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CCN", "javascript:ShowCommentPopUp({0});") %>'>Add
</asp:HyperLink>
```

where CCN is my column in gridview. This will actually pass the ccn in which the row is clicked:

I want to pass two more params: "Name" and "Status" are the corresponding columns as the 2nd and 3rd arguments for the ShowCommentPopUp function. I tried many ways, but ended up in all syntax errors. Lot of time is invested.

for example:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval(["CCN", "NAME", "javascript:ShowCommentPopUp({0}, {1});")
```

etc etc

if anyone can help me, it is greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Aparna

Comment: There is a [ character inside your Eval call...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `NavigateUrl='<%# Eval(["CCN", "NAME"], "javascript:ShowCommentPopUp({0}, {1});")`?

Answer (score 1):

Using this code you can solve your problem:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypComment" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" NavigateUrl="#" OnClick="<%# String.Format("javascript:return ShowCommentPopup(""{0}"",""{1}"")",Eval("CCN"),Eval("parametername"))  %>">
    Add
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and lots of problems to get it to work.

Eventually this worked for me: you have to place the resulting values of the eval functions between quotes. And these quotes must be html save, so replace the ' character into '

For me at least, only then my dialog, containing the three parameters showed.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" CssClass="btnmaatwerksmall" runat="server" Text="Wijzig"
       OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("OpenChildNietInEnterprise(&apos;{0}&apos;,&apos;{1}&apos;,&apos;{2}&apos;);", Eval("CursusNaam"), Eval("VerwachteOmzetJaar"), Eval("VerwachteOmzetKomendeJaren")) %>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
```